# How to do Framework7 routing with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-framework-7

I am developing a hybrid mobile app with Framework7. I finished the user interface successfully and now I want to add functionality to my app. My problem is the navigation from one .html to another. 
At the user interface i did the navigation with links, like this:

```
<a href="/homepage/" class="button button-fill button-login">LOGIN</a>
```

Because of some checks I removed the whole **href-tag** and here I come to the problem, **how can i do this linking in jQuery**?

I tried a lot, also followed the public "Router JavaScript API" (https://v1.framework7.io/docs/router-api.html) but nothing worked well (NOTE: this is not my whole code, just the affected parts):

1. Attempt 1

   var myApp = new Framework7 ({}); 
   var mainView = myApp.views.add('.view-main');

   var app = { 
     init: function () { 
       events.doClickFunctions(); 
     }, 
     login: { 
       success: function () { 
         //here should be the linking done 
         mainView.router.load('/homepage/'); 
       } 
     } 
   };

Problem: "myApp.views.add is not a function"

2. Attempt 2

var myApp = new Framework7 ({});
 var mainView = myApp.addView('.view-main');

var app = {

```
    init: function () {
        events.doClickFunctions();
    },
    login: {
        success: function () {
            //here should be the linking done
            mainView.router.load('/homepage/');
        }
    }
};
```

Problem: "myApp.addView is not a function"

And i tried some other combinations, but nothing worked.

Furthermore, I made a workaround: If the checks are successful, the href attribute will be added with jQuery and a virtual click is made on the element. So the user experience is like i want it to, but I guess thats not how it is supposed to work?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: which version of framework you are using?

Comment: I am using Framework7 2.1.3

Comment: you need to add router. have you added it. check router in Framework7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### try this

```
        var app = new Framework7({
  id: 'io.framework7.testapp',
  precompileTemplates: true, //
  template7Pages: true,
  root: '#app',
  theme: theme,
  cache: false ,/* disable caching */
  data: function () {


  },
  methods: {
    helloWorld: function () {
      app.dialog.alert('Hello World!');
    },
  },
  routes: routes,
  vi: {
    placementId: 'pltd4o7ibb9rc653x14',
  }
});
app.views.main.router.navigate('/login/');
```

for routing to another Page in jq use this :

```
  app.views.main.router.navigate('/login/');
```

---